# How do you reveal the text of a JPasswordField

Tags: java, swing, jpasswordfield

I'm making a Authentication app in java and i want to add a JRadioButton, where if it is selected it will allow you to see the text in the JPasswordField, i was trying to figure it out and i was just wondering is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Java-Doc of the [`setEchoChar()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#setEchoChar(char)) method:

> Setting a value of 0 indicates that you wish to see the text as it is typed, similar to the behavior of a standard JTextField.

So just use:

```
second.setEchoChar((char)0);
```

to set and to reset:

```
second.setEchoChar('\u2022');
```

The default `EchoChar` is determined by the Look & Feel. To be always in harmony with the theme it's the best to save the default `EchoChar` before changing it the first time:

```
char originalEchoChar = second.getEchoChar();
```

Comment: How would i set it back to the dots though?

Comment: just use the old value again (e.g. '*')

Comment: in what way, i tried this second.setEchoChar((char)*); and the '*' is highlighted in red.

Comment: you wont need the `(char)` here instead: `second.setEchoChar('*');`

Comment: The JTextField is using a bullet point, would there be any way to get that?

Comment: @BillNye I took me a while to get it, but it's rly simple, just use the unicode bullet icon, check my edit. The default Echo Char is determent by the look and feel and is by default the bullet. To be sure to be always in collaboration with the theme you can call `getEchoChar` before changing the char the first time and store this value for the reset